# Traefik 2.0 behind docker swarm not working

Tags: docker-swarm, traefik

So, I'm trying to use Traefik to load-balance my web apps via docker swarm.

However, I already tried many configurations but somehow not works. I already read the documentation and read some articles in the internet. Unfortunately, many articles references traefik 1.x instead traefik 2.0.

Here is my docker-stack.yml for traefik

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:2.0
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
        - node.role == manager
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      labels:
      - traefik.docker.network=load_balancer
    configs:
    - source: traefik
      target: /etc/traefik/traefik.yml
    ports:
    - 80:80
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
    - load_balancer
configs:
  traefik:
    file: ./traefik.yml
networks:
  load_balancer:
    external: true
    name: load_balancer
```

whoami.yml (for testing purpose)

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    deploy:
      labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=load_balancer
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.docker.localhost`)
    networks:
    - load_balancer
networks:
  load_balancer:
    external: true
    name: load_balancer
```

My traefik.yml

```
log:
  level: DEBUG

api:
  insecure: true

providers:
  docker:
    exposedByDefault: false
    swarmMode: true
    watch: true
```

docker network ls

```
hxjw9rytw3od        load_balancer       overlay             swarm
```

curl -H Host:whoami.docker.localhost http://127.0.0.1

```
404 page not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to add entrypoints declaration in your config: https://docs.traefik.io/routing/entrypoints/

Answer (score 1):

I hope is not too late to answer this. I've found the solution.

First, you can either use `traefik.yml` for configuration or use traefik cli flags in [docker-compose command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command) field.

Here is the working approach if you use `traefik.yml` as your main configuration.
It is [recommended](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/file/#directory) to use `directory` over `file`.

`traefik.yml`

```yaml
log:
  level: DEBUG

api:
  insecure: true

# This is required
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ':80'
  websecure:
    address: ':443'

providers:
  file: # Required, if you use traefik.yml as your main configuration
    directory: /etc/traefik
    watch: true
  docker:
    exposedByDefault: false
    swarmMode: true
    watch: true
```

Working approach if you use traefik cli flags

`docker-compose.stack.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:2.0
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
        - node.role == manager
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    command:
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --ping=true
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --providers.docker.swarmmode=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=load_balancer
      - --providers.docker.watch=true
    ports:
    - 80:80
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
    - load_balancer
networks:
  load_balancer:
    external: true
    name: load_balancer
```

`whoami.yml` (for testing purpose)

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    deploy:
      labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=load_balancer
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.docker.localhost`)
      - traefik.http.services.whoami.loadbalancer.server.port=80
    networks:
    - load_balancer
networks:
  load_balancer:
    external: true
    name: load_balancer
```

Test via curl

```sh
curl -H Host:whoami.docker.localhost 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to Not use traefik.yml but to use the cli args to configure your instance.

You can make it like this :

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  ingress:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    networks:
      - ingress-net
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      # TCP Port if needed for any service you have
      - "60000:60000"
    command:
      ###                          ###
      # Traefik Global Configuration #
      ###                          ###
      # Enable DEBUG logs
      - "--log.level=DEBUG" # DEBUG, INFO, etc...
      - "--ping=true"
      # Enable api access without authentification (only GET route so it only possible to get IPs)
      - "--api.insecure=true" # You can insecure here, because It accessible only in the container if you didn't open the port.
      # Set the provider to Docker
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      # Set the docker network
      - "--providers.docker.network=ingress-net"
      # Set to docker swarm cluster
      - "--providers.docker.swarmMode=true"
      # If False : Do not expose containers to the web by default
      - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
      # Default rule to service-name.example.com
      - "--providers.docker.defaultRule=Host(`{{ trimPrefix `/` .Name }}.example.com`)"
      # Default http port
      - "--entrypoints.http.address=:80"
      # Default https port
      - "--entrypoints.https.address=:443"
      # Enable let's encrypt
      - "--certificatesResolvers.certbot=true"
      - "--certificatesResolvers.certbot.acme.httpChallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesResolvers.certbot.acme.httpChallenge.entrypoint=http"
      - "--certificatesResolvers.certbot.acme.email=admin@example.com"
      - "--certificatesResolvers.certbot.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
      # TCP Entrypoint if needed
      - "--entrypoints.tcpendpointname.address=:60000"

    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./acme.json:/letsencrypt/acme.json

    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        ###               ###
        # Traefik Dashboard #
        ###               ###
        # Enable this endpoint
        - traefik.enable=true
        ##
        # Http
        #
        # Set the service route
        - traefik.http.routers.ingress_http.rule=Host(`ingress.example.com`)
        # Set the entrypoint (http or https)
        - traefik.http.routers.ingress_http.entrypoints=http
        # Rule to redirect to http to https
        - traefik.http.middlewares.ingress-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
        # Enable Https redirection
        - traefik.http.routers.ingress_http.middlewares=ingress-https-redirect@docker
        #
        ##

        ##
        # Https
        #
        - traefik.http.routers.ingress_https.rule=Host(`ingress.example.com`)
        # Set the entrypoint (http or https)
        - traefik.http.routers.ingress_https.entrypoints=https
        # Enable Let's encrypt auto certificat creation
        - traefik.http.routers.ingress_https.tls.certresolver=certbot
        # Enable authentification
        - traefik.http.routers.ingress_https.middlewares=ingress-auth@
        # Uncommant this to enable basic authentification
        # - traefik.http.middlewares.ingress-auth.basicauth.users=admin:$$this$$is$$encrypted$$password
        #
        ##

        ##
        # TCP Endpoint
        #
        # Set the service route
        - "traefik.tcp.routers.tcpendpointname.rule=HostSNI(`*`)"
        # Here you can set the host uri if you use tls only.
        # - "traefik.tcp.routers.tcpendpointname.rule=HostSNI(`tcp.example.com`)"
        # - "traefik.tcp.routers.tcpendpointname.tls=true"
        # Set the entrypoin
        - "traefik.tcp.routers.tcpendpointname.entrypoints=tcpendpointname"
        #
        ##

        ##
        # Service
        #
        # Set the service port
        - traefik.http.services.ingress.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
        #
        ##
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager

networks:
  ingress-net:
    external: true
```

I hope this will Help you.

You can use the same labels for any other containers, that work with the same logic.

Comment: I don't think it is any helpful to suggest a different approach with completely different context instead of tryingto understand the OP's setup first. It won't help other visitors of this thread either.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've got a `404 page not found` Traefik seems to be available.

However, when using **curl** to fetch http://127.0.0.1 this IP address is going to be content of request's `Host` header field. This in turn is used by Traefik for routing the request. Since your whoami service is meant to match requests for Host `whoami.docker.localhost` this given response of Traefik is just fine.

Have you tried fetching http://whoami.docker.localhost instead? You might need to inject this hostname into hosts **/etc/hosts** files prior to testing with **curl**.

```
127.0.0.1 whoami.docker.localhost
```

Optionally, you can try manual HTTP request with a tool like **netcat** (sometimes available as **nc**):

```
# netcat 127.0.0.1 80
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: whoami.docker.localhost
```

You need to press Enter twice after entering second line of request as required by HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

**Port Detection**

Docker Swarm does not provide any [port detection](https://docs.traefik.io/providers/docker/#port-detection) information to Traefik.

Therefore you must specify the port to use for communication by using the label traefik.http.services.<service_name>.loadbalancer.server.port (Check the reference for this label in the [routing section for Docker](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/providers/docker/#port)).

Answer (score -1):

Traefik's service discovery with Docker requires [container labels instead of image labels](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#labels-1) (check [traefik's quickstart](https://docs.traefik.io/getting-started/quick-start/)).

The following minimal working example works on docker swarm:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:2.0
    command: --providers.docker
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    labels:   # defining a container label instead of an image label
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.docker.localhost`)"
```

Comment: I don't think this particular example is working with Docker **Swarm**. Your links' targets are okay, though intentionally focusing on wrong solution. Labels must be defined per service in `deploy:` container. See [related docs](https://docs.traefik.io/providers/docker/#docker-swarm-mode): _While in Swarm Mode, Traefik uses labels found on services, not on individual containers._

Comment: @ThomasUrban my example is a minimal working example of a multi-app, multi-network docker stack deployment I am running right now with Traefik2.0 as the ingress controller.  Fire up an "hello world" example to give it a try.

Comment: Hm, I'm running Traefik with Docker swarm myself, so there is something odd for sure. I'm just pointing out that your post seems to state contradictorily and it seems to do so in opposition to what is stated on Traefik's docs itself. You state "requires container labels" ... Traefik says "labels found on services, not on individual containers" ... so, it might be working for you now, but it is still in opposition to what is suggested by Traefik. In that case I'd rather stick with official suggestions to be as future-proof as possible.